# Scala nondeterministic / caches classes?

Tags: scala, scalac

I have a very simple goal: to compile a Scala class, and then load it from within another Scala script.  The problem is that Scala seems to cache (not sure where) the classes that I create, and doesn't respect subsequent changes.

The following lines create a directory with two .scala files, compiles one, and runs the other:

```
mkdir test
cd test
echo 'class MyClass(s: String)' > MyClass.scala
echo 'val p = new MyClass("ok")' > test.scala
scalac MyClass.scala
scala test.scala # this works
cd ..
rm -rf test
```

If I run the above lines, I need to REBOOT MY COMPUTER for the lines below to work:

```
mkdir test
cd test
echo 'class MyClass()' > MyClass.scala
echo 'val p = new MyClass()' > test.scala
scalac MyClass.scala
scala test.scala # this doesn't
cd ..
rm -rf test
```

If I don't reboot, I get an error that I'm missing a String in my constructor. Not sure where in Scala-land it's caching the previous String-based constructor.

Comment: Agree, reproducible on OSX 10.8.3, scala 2.10.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the scala script runner starts a resident instance of the compile server (`fsc`) in the background. You should be able to find a running `java` process with main class `scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer` after running your first script.

Note that this only happens when `scala` is used to run a script, that is, a `.scala` file that does **not** contain a single compilation unit with a main class.

Subsequent calls to `scala` will use this compile server (only when used to run a script), which caches information about previous compilation runs, hence the error.

You can instruct scala not to use `fsc` when running a script with:

```
scala -nc test.scala
```

You can also shut down that background instance with:

```
fsc -shutdown
```

Or reset its cache with:

```
fsc -reset
```

Comment: Would not have figured that out in a million years. Very sneaky ... thanks!